# Installation with wine error

Tags: wine, programming

I downloaded vds 6.0 (a script type programming language for windows OS's) and now I am trying to install it in ubuntu 14.04. I looked at wine app database and I found that vds 6 works on wine. Here have a look at it https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=13983. It is gold rated!! 
But I am unable to run it. When I right click on it and open with wine, nothing occurs. The arrow gets busy for sometime and then resets. Then I did so from the terminal.

> rehanullahafridi@rehanullahafridi:~/.wine/dosdevices/c:/visual-dialogscript-60[R1PP3R]$ wine start setup.exe

Setup.exe is the vds(visual dialog script) setup file.
And the result was:

> fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100

Just this nothing more is displayed. I googled around google but all in vain. Please help me going with this. Much thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Are you running the newest version of wine? The test results are from Ubuntu 8.04 on wine version 1.1.5 and nothing was tested other than running the demo. This data is from your link.

Comment: @ElderGeek Yeah, I am using newest version of wine i.e. wine 1.6.2. I searched all over the net for wine 1.1.5 and found it no where (it was just a test version, you may know). Now will I have to install ubuntu 8.04 and wine 1.1.5 just for running this applet? Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that course of action. I'll write up an answer that covers what I would do in your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the "gold" result linked indicates only that the demo was tested and runnable under a very old version of both wine and Ubuntu, what I would do is install virtualbox under Ubuntu, install a supported version of Windows on a virtual machine and then install vds 6.0 on the VM. this approach will virtually guarantee compatibility (I've been forced to do the same with Windows software in the past with good results). If anything is unclear drop me a comment and I'll do my best to clarify.

Comment: Thanks alot. Seems to be a good idea. Will I have to buy a windows license to run in Virtual Machine?

Comment: If the machine you want to use it on already has a license sticker attached for the version you need to run, no. If not, yes.

Comment: Yeah. I am using hp and on its top a sticker for windows 7 pro serial number is attached. I searched around on google and found that VMWare Player named thing is good for making virtual machine so I downloaded it and installed. Now it requires a windows disc. I hope you will be willing to direct me to a working windows 7 iso image website. (I downloaded windows 7 iso's from softpedia and getintopc.com separately(2.6GB each) but the vmware warns me during installation that they are corrupted and I remain watching the screen! Quite frustrating!!). I hope You may share with me. Thanks as usual.

Comment: This is a different question and off-topic here. Be that as it may, a quick google search results in http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-recovery where you can enter your product key and download the ISO

Answer (score 0):

Open "Configure Wine" from the dash and try different versions of Windows. It often helps.

Comment: I have tried Windows vista, seven, eight, xp, 2003, 8. All which are present in winecfg.